# How to swap row and columns Panda

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-api

Im trying to fetch data using Yahoo's API to get stock prices, and show them on an excel sheet. All works fine except when I try to transpose the data I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Data Source
import yfinance as yf

#DATA
stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'NEE', 'AMGN', 'TU', 'ZM', 'TSLA', 'TTD', 'SEDG', 'APPN', 'TWLO', 'MMM', 'ABBV', 'SHW', 'K', 'HON', 'AFL', 'JNJ', 'ABT', 'EMR', 'FSLR', 'SPWR', 'ENPH', 'ACC.OL']
data = yf.download(tickers=stocks, period='3d', interval='1d')

#Clean data
columns = ["Adj Close", "High", "Low", "Open", "Volume"]
data.drop(columns=columns, axis=1, inplace=True)

data = data.T

#Remove timezone
data.index = data.index.tz_localize(None)

#Print data
print(data)

#Send to excel
datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter("FromPython.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Sheet1')
datatoexcel.save()
```

Can somebody explain what's going wrong and how I can fix? Thank you!

Comment: you are transposing the data so the index is now columns, try `data.columns = data.columns.tz_localize(None)` instead of using `index`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `data.T` the `DataFrame`'s index is composed of your symbols, which have no timezone. Maybe you want to remove timezone before transposing?